# Is it possible to toggle Google Analytics on/off via jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am looking to create a solution for GDPR where I can toggle Google Analytics on/off as a result of clicking on some  buttons - I am looking at a way to either add the GA script block to the head which I don't seem to make work - or perhaps a way to include the base block of script and then pass or remove the window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true; parameter to the code block... Is this possible?

```
function addInGACode () {
$('head').append('<script src="ga.js"><\/script>');
}
```

Appears to add the script to the head - but how can I remove it via another function?

Comment: You can't unload GA once loaded, the appropriate way to address the issue is to only include the script once the dialog has been approved.

Comment: Thanks - how do I go about including the script once approved then?

Comment: Do you have option to use `gtag.js` instead of `ga.js`?

Comment: Not sure - whats the difference? I assume if the main block of GA code is placed on a page but the script link to the ga.js file is not there - it does not fire?